# non-unique objects in array splicing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a new array out of two existing arrays.

- There's a totalStock variable containing every item in the store.
- There's a currentStock containing the items that are currently in stock
- Now I need a outStock that contains the items that are not in stock, problem is that some of the items share the same name, because of that it is throwing out the wrong result

In the stock arrays there are objects sharing the same `id`. The result of the following code should be an array containing the objects with `id` Metal and Wood but it's returning only Metal.

```
 var totalStock = [
    {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Metal'}, {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Stone'}
];

var inStock = [
    {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Stone'} /* Metal is no longer in stock, nor is Wood */
];

var outStock = totalStock.filter(item => {
  return !inStock.some(inStockItem => inStockItem.id === item.id);
});

console.log(outStock); /* This only returns Metal but should also be returning wood */
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fnh4dou9/22/)

**Updated Code**

```
var totalStock = [
    {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Metal'}, {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Stone'}
];

var inStock = [
    {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Wood'}, {id:'Stone'} /* Metal is no longer in stock, nor is Wood */
];

function calculateStock(stockArray){
    var totalStockAmount = {};
  stockArray.forEach(function(item){
    totalStockAmount[item.id] = 0;
  });

  stockArray.forEach(function(item){
    totalStockAmount[item.id] = totalStockAmount[item.id] + 1;
  });
  return totalStockAmount;
}

var totalStockAmount = calculateStock(totalStock),
        totalInStockAmount = calculateStock(inStock);

Object.keys(totalStockAmount).forEach(function(stock){
    if(!totalInStockAmount[stock]) totalInStockAmount[stock] = 0;
    totalInStockAmount[stock] = totalStockAmount[stock] - totalInStockAmount[stock];
 });

var noStockAmount = totalInStockAmount,
        noStock = [];

Object.keys(noStockAmount).forEach(function(stock){
    var amount = noStockAmount[stock];
  for(var x = 0; x < amount; x++){
    noStock.push({id:stock});
  }
});

console.log(noStock);
```

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. You got lucky to get that filter code from previous question that didn't clearly specify your problem.. But to then copy that to a new question in order to have others make it more robust is just not how this site works. The objective here is for you to attempt to solve your own issues and others help you fix **your code**

Comment: @charlietfl then at least tell me what to google for, lol. I have been browsing for hours tryna find this question

Comment: I gave you an outline below of basic process. Now attempt the first part yourself. When you run into problems there show us what you tried

Comment: see updated code :3

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a comparison of the counts for each.

Create a hashmap of counts for inStock that would look something like:

```
{Wood:2, Stone:1}
```

Then you can deduct as you filter through the totalStock and if that property doesn't exist or is zero you know it is out of stock

Comment: see updated code, I feel like I made it way to complicated but it works I guess.

Comment: Here's perhaps a simpler version using filter and reduce https://jsfiddle.net/fnh4dou9/38/

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to fix this ultimately is to make more sense of your data structure. I'm struggling to understand everything, but it seems like ID is a non-unique key meaning type? And I presume more data is with it? And outOfStock means...I can't tell, cos you say Wood is out of stock but there are clearly 2 in stock. I guess that's...different wood? So out of stock is an array of items meaning at least one is sold? I'm...gonna work of that assuption but I'm probably misunderstanding.

You need to have some unique identifier if those are different things. And, well, that should probably be what ID is.

---

I'd suggest having one object that contains all your products (possibly keyed by ID for easy retrieval) and just use IDs to store what's in/out of stock, so you aren't duplicating data.

e.g.

```
var products = {
    1001: {
        id: 1001,
        type: 'wood',
        otherData: 'redwood',
    },
    1002: {
        id: 1002,
        type: 'wood',
        otherData: 'oak',
    },
    1003: {
        id: 1003,
        type: 'stone',
        otherData: 'limestone',
    },
    // etc
}


var totalStock = {
    1001: 4,
    1002: 4,
    1003: 6,
}

var inStock = {
    1001: 2,
    1002: 0,
    1003: 1,
}

var outStock = Object.keys(totalStock).filter(id => !inStock[id]); // [1002]
```

I think I'm misunderstanding something about what you want each piece of data to be, but flattening your data like this is gonna give you a much easier time and probably solve a lot of these issues.